# call on class click function in asp.net code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a function!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tstInfo").on("click",function(){
       $.toast({
        heading: 'Welcome to my Elite admin',
        text: 'Use the predefined ones, or specify a custom position object.',
        position: 'top-right',
        loaderBg:'#ff6849',
        icon: 'info',
        hideAfter: 3000, 
        stack: 6
      });

 }); });
```

I want to call it from code behind in asp.net
please tell me how to do it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at `$.ajax` in the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: When do you want to call it? on load?

Comment: @Eddi = `$ajax` is helpful when you want to call from client to server , but from server to client its not possible with it

Comment: @hardkoded yeah on load

Comment: In what situation do you want it to be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like this

```
protected void BtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "id", 
      "<script language='javascript'> $('.tstInfo').click();</script>", true);            

}
```

Comment: you probably forgot to escape the double quotes